# rename xml using specific node random position

Tags: batch-file

Hello friends I am trying to rename a group of xml files based on a specific node, which always changes position.
[image]
So far I have the following code that always works in the same position, but as I say the position I need is variable.

The node that I need is the one that I set in image noIdentificacion =

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%Z in ('dir /b *.xml') do (

   for /f "tokens=12 delims== " %%A in (

     'find /i "noIdentificacion=" ^< "%%Z"'

       ) do ren "%%Z" "%%A.xml"
)
```

I hope and they can support me. Thank you.

sorry atach EG

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><cfdi:Comprobante 

         <cfdi:DomicilioFiscal calle="Paseo" codigoPostal="123123" 
  colonia="LOMAS" estado="DF" localidad="MEXICO D.F." municipio="Cuajimalpa 
  de 
 Morelos" noExterior="400B" noInterior="P3" pais="MEXICO" />
 <cfdi:ExpedidoEn pais="Mexico" referencia="AA000771139" />
    <cfdi:RegimenFiscal Regimen="Régimen General de las Personas Morales" />
 </cfdi:Emisor>
 <cfdi:Conceptos>
 <cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1.00" descripcion="ROLL" importe="270505.28" 
 noIdentificacion="99994HWR3929" unidad="EA" valorUnitario="270505.28">
  <cfdi:ComplementoConcepto>
<ventavehiculos:InformacionAduanera aduana="Eagle Pass" fecha="2017-06-19" 
numero="172736007007111" />
</ventavehiculos:VentaVehiculos>
</cfdi:ComplementoConcepto>
</cfdi:Concepto>
</cfdi:Conceptos>
<cfdi:Impuestos totalImpuestosTrasladados="43943.38">
        <cfdi:Traslados>
              <cfdi:Traslado importe="43943.38" impuesto="IVA" tasa="16" />
       </cfdi:Traslados>
  </cfdi:Impuestos>
  <cfdi:Complemento>
 Lg4NRnJDXIqvehu8vEyugAePTdHluCgD32E=" version="1.0" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital 
 http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigital.xsd" 
 xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" />
 </cfdi:Complemento>
 </cfdi:Comprobante>
```

Comment: You should never show example text in images, but as code-text instead. If we want to test your code, how we can generate the example text? Do you expect we type it from the image? **`:(`**

Comment: The code appears to rename each xml file not a group of xml files. Regardless, due to the possible line lengths and randomness of the search string, you would be advised to look at an alternative to batch files for this task, _perhaps powershell_.

Comment: Sorry, I just attached an example.

Answer (score 0):

The following ***commented*** script should do the job:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
REM Change the current directory: your choice
pushd "D:\bat\SO\files"
REM Get a static list of `xml` files
for /f "delims=" %%Z in ('dir /b *.xml') do (
    set "_noIdentificacion="                             REM clear a sentinel flag
    REM Search for a particular text string in a file
    for /f "delims=" %%A in ( 'find /i "noIdentificacion=" ^< "%%Z"' ) do (
        REM The FOR command is mostly used to process a set of one or more files, 
        REM     but you can also process a set of one or more text strings: 
        for %%G in ( %%A ) do (
            REM debugging output
            echo debug %%G
            REM found the particular text string in the line?
            if /I "%%~G"=="noIdentificacion" (
                set "_noIdentificacion=noIdentificacion" REM set the sentinel flag
            ) else (
                if defined _noIdentificacion (
                    REM debugging output
                    echo found noIdentificacion in file "%%~Z": "%%~G"
                    REM check as to whether a file isn't renamed already 
                    if EXIST "%%~Z" if /I "%%~Z" NEQ "%%~G.xml" (
                        REM remove ECHO from next line no sooner than debugged
                        ECHO   ren "%%~Z" "%%~G.xml"
                    )
                )
                set "_noIdentificacion="                 REM clear the sentinel flag
            )
        )
    )
)
REM Change directory back to the path/folder most recently stored by the PUSHD command.
popd
```

**Sample result** with all debugging output data:

```
==> D:\bat\SO\q45449070.bat
debug <cfdi:Concepto
debug cantidad
debug "1.00"
debug descripcion
debug "ROLL"
debug importe
debug "270505.28"
debug noIdentificacion
debug "99994HWR3929"
found noIdentificacion in file "45449070.xml": "99994HWR3929"
  ren "45449070.xml" "99994HWR3929.xml"
debug unidad
debug "EA"
debug valorUnitario
debug "270505.28">

==>
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, you saved my life, you do exactly what I require.

best regards.

Comment: @PAPIPAPI If this answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.